# Write data to text file from array of objects in Java

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class ReaderWriter extends Bank {

private final String FILENAME = "clients.txt";

public void writeToFile() {
    int i = 0;
    boolean repeat = true;
    Formatter output = null;   // Used to write to file

    try {
        output = new Formatter(FILENAME);
        // Open the file

        while ((i <= accounts.length - 1) && (accounts[i] != null)) {
            output.format("%s\n", accounts[i].getAccountHolder());      
            output.format("%d%n", accounts[i].getAccountNumber());
            output.format("%d%n", accounts[i].getAmount());
            i = i + 1;
        }catch (Exception ex) {

        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        output.close();                 // Make sure to close the resource after usage.
    }
}
```

And this is `Bank` class:

```
public class Bank {

public final int MAX_NUMBER_OF_ACCOUNTS = 10;
public int max = 0;

String name1;
int money1;
int number1;

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
BankAccount[] accounts = new BankAccount[MAX_NUMBER_OF_ACCOUNTS];
public void greateAccount() {
    int i = 0;
    boolean repeate2 = true;
    System.out.println("You have chosen to create a new account.");
    System.out.println("Enter the name of the account holder:  ");
    name1 = input.next();

    System.out.println("Enter the account no.");
    number1 = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter the initiating amount: ");
    money1 = input.nextInt();

    while (repeate2 == true) {
        if (accounts[i] == null) {
            if (i < 1) {
                accounts[i] = new BankAccount();
                accounts[i].setAccountHolder(name1);
                accounts[i].setAccountNumber(number1);
                accounts[i].setAmount(money1);
                repeate2 = false;
            } else {
                if (ifAccountExist(number1) != true) {
                    accounts[i] = new BankAccount();
                    accounts[i].setAccountHolder(name1);
                    accounts[i].setAccountNumber(number1);
                    accounts[i].setAmount(money1);
                    repeate2 = false;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("****This account ALREADY EXIST!****");
                    System.out.println("*************************************");
                    System.out.println();
                    max = max - 1;
                    repeate2 = false;
                }
            }
        }
        i = i + 1;
    }
    max++;
}
```

Now I want to write to text file account number, name and money. 
My code doesn't work. I does not write it can not retrieve values from array I don't know why?
Can you help me?

Comment: I can't compiled your code..

Comment: it doesn't seem like _your_ code first of all

Comment: what doesn't work specifically and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is not going to compile, for many reasons...

For example:

1. Why this line:

   ex.printStackTrace();

   is floating in your class ReaderWriter (line 21) and away a catch block?
2. Why you don't have **include** declarations?

Comment: Thet was my mistake writing here :) it is compiling. The problem is when i try to write in file it does not find anything in array. It seas accounts[0] == null but that is not true. I don't understad why?

Comment: It's hard to know without see the rest of your code. I can see many irregularities in the logic. Also the lines `name1 = input.next();`, `number1 = input.nextInt();`, and `money1 = input.nextInt();` seem suspicious. Verify the values of `number1`, `money1` and `name1` before continue. Finally at the lines `if(accounts[i] == null)` and `if (i < 1)`, you should really fix the logic,  It is not going to enter in these parts at least more that one time, because `i < 1` just one iteration and  you have set `repeate2 = false;` what means that the `while` loop is reached just once.

Comment: whole program is running ass a loop. i can enter more than one account and it saves then in array. then I can print all or just one account in console. Every thing is fine. first loop should enter just onse. when I enter first account. then when I want to enter secend account it goeas to the secont loop. just chacking that I don't eneter same account number. Whole progam is working. I just need to add write accounts to file. And next time when I start program I need to reads accounts from a file.